# I have upgrade the php version 7.2 to 7.4 now getting error in myphpadmin panel. i am attaching the screenshort

Tags: php, ubuntu

```
Notice in ./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1229
 Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Backtrace

./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1349: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeadersForColumns(
array,
array,
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` ',
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#4427: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeaders(
array,
array,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` ',
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1686: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1980: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
string '476770',
integer 25,
NULL,
,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2199: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
,
array,
string 'tren_wp2',
string 'wp_postmeta',
NULL,
NULL,
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string '476770',
integer 25,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`',
NULL,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'tren_wp2',
string 'wp_postmeta',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'tren_wp2',
string 'wp_postmeta',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

[image]

Comment: please post what you pasted in a proper and readable format. better copy and paste in some file and then set it up for us to have a better look

Comment: are you using phpMyAdmin 5.0.1 ? if not upgrade. better yet, stop using it. On Mac, use Sequel Pro. On Windows, use HeidiSQL. On Linux, MySQL workbench

Answer (score 11):

You can edit the file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php`

in the specific line `#XXXX` 
Search `$col_visib[$j]` and add `?? false`

`$col_visib[$j] ?? false`

in your case

```
list($order_link, $sorted_header_html)
    = $this->_getOrderLinkAndSortedHeaderHtml(
        $fields_meta[$i], $sort_expression,
        $sort_expression_nodirection, $i, $unsorted_sql_query,
        $session_max_rows, $comments,
        $sort_direction, $col_visib,
        $col_visib[$j] ?? false
    );
```

Ps. On Debian works also

have fun

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the repository and run an upgrade.

**Steps**

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: this didn't work for me. there were some errors. i rather suggest to follow the tutorial how to install official release of phpmyadmin https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, whenever you are going to upgrade PHP version 7.2 to 7.4 you must upgrade all module which means PHPMyAdmin, apache et.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the phpMyAdmin cookies in the browser, the error disappears. PHP version: 7.4.1, phpMyAdmin version: 4.9.5